# html5 canvas in durandal

Tags: html, canvas, durandal

i am trying to use the html5 canvas element to draw in durandal without success

the markup

```
 <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </body>
```

the js

```
define(function() {

   function viewAttached() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
    buffer.width = buffer.height = 60;
    var bctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
    bctx.translate(30, 30);
    bctx.rotate(0.5);
    bctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    bctx.fillRect(-15, -15, 30, 30);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 30, 30);
    ctx.drawImage(buffer, 50, 50);
    }
    var ctor = function () {
    this.viewAttached = viewAttached();
    return ctor;
    };
  });
```

the problem is that canvas doesn't load so all what i can see is an empty canvas. the same code is working well in jsfiddle i mean only jquery and canvas but when i transfer it to durandal it doesnt work anymore  can anybody help?

Comment: You have an extra set of parenthesis in the line: `this.viewAttached = viewAttached();` it should be: `this.viewAttached = viewAttached;`. Why do you tagged your question with knockout? Because I don't see any knockout related code in your question...

Comment: @nemesv concerning the viewAttached() it s working like that and it s how i define my function and about knockout its beacause durandal is using knockout and if a solution is provide with knockout it will be the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned it is working with viewAttached(), but in fact in your question you mention that it is indeed not working.   My best bet is that A: nemesv is right and you may be firing that function, but not in the way you intend and B: Your view isn't actually attached when you call viewAttached.

This works in Durandal 1.2 -

```
define(function() {

   function viewAttached() {
       // Do stuff
    }
    var viewModel = {
        viewAttached: viewAttached;
    };

    return viewModel;
  });
```

If you are using Durandal 2.0, do it like this -

```
define(function() {

   function attached() {
       // Do stuff
    }
    var viewModel = {
        attached: attached;
    };

    return viewModel;
  });
```

That assumes you are using the router.  You don't need to fire the constructor, Durandal handles that for you.  You also don't need to call viewAttached, because Durandal handles that at the proper point in the loading cycle (after the DOM is ready)  http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/